# Local Development Server Errors

Tags: python, django, visual-studio-code, server

```
Exception happened during processing of request from ('127.0.0.1', 56261)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Name\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\socketserver.py", line 650, in process_request_thread
    self.finish_request(request, client_address)
  File "C:\Users\Name\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\socketserver.py", line 360, in finish_request
    self.RequestHandlerClass(request, client_address, self)
  File "C:\Users\Name\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\socketserver.py", line 720, in __init__
    self.handle()
  File "C:\Users\Name\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\core\servers\basehttp.py", line 174, in handle
    self.handle_one_request()
  File "C:\Users\Name\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\core\servers\basehttp.py", line 182, in handle_one_request
    self.raw_requestline = self.rfile.readline(65537)
  File "C:\Users\Name\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\socket.py", line 669, in readinto
    return self._sock.recv_into(b)
ConnectionAbortedError: [WinError 10053] An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine
```

Comment: please add more details to question.

Answer (score 1):

Try running the server on a different port ie. `Python manage.py runserver 8000`